# Could not find crash report on Google Play Console

Tags: android, google-play-console

I have developed an android mobile application and uploaded it to the google play console. Then I have opened the app for internal testing and set some of the known testers.

when one of the testers check the app it crashed. Then he sent feedback. I have already set my email as a feedback email when I set the testers for internal testing. The thing is there is no mail regarding the crash. How can I find the crash report? In the Google play console, **Crashes and ANRs** section also empty

This is how he sent the feedback

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Maybe it is late, but for internal testing, you can find your crash reports in Play Console under **Pre-launch reports** menu.

Comment: You sir are my hero!